# How to create a 100% memory spike with a bash command

Tags: linux

Please let us know how to produce 100% memory usage in Linux.

I know how can we produce 100% CPU Spike but for my testing purpose i need to make 100% memory usage.

Please let me know is there any way to make 100% memory usage

Regards
Arun

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fill memory with random data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260472/fill-memory-with-random-data)

Comment: Please note, that in Linux (or in any modern OS probably), "memory usage" and "100% memory usage" have no straight-forward meanings.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that 100% memory usage is likely to create an unstable system. But you may get close by using the stress command with the -vm argument.